# Updating status of terminated workflows

Tags: workflow, task-list

I have a bunch of terminated workflows due to many reasons mostly inability(not catching exceptions) to send emails as part of task assignment. After the code has been fixed, is there a way to programatically revive those terminated workflows and to put them "in progress" from "error occurred". The worksflows are sequential custom workflows. One of the main reasons why I couldn't simply terminate and restart the workflows is that there are comments in the tasks that I would like to retain. Restarting the workflow will delete the tasks and teh comments will be lost

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to put these workflows back to 'In Progress' - once they have been terminated their state is essentially locked in the database. I have attempted to do something similar but outside of the workflow you cannot modify an SPWorkflow. I think the only way would be to terminate them properly.

You could perhaps write some code to pull any comments etc from the relevant tasks lists and the hidden workflow history list and archive this off somewhere.

Sorry I couldn't be any more help!

Alex